# How to display location title in info window of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm generating a link to google maps and passing in an address as follows:

https://www.google.com/maps?q=some+address

This works great, but I would also like to display a name in the info box that is displayed in google maps.  Currently, only the address is displayed

How may I do this?

I've been unable to identify the parameter to pass in the URL string.

Comment: Could you provide an example? If I use `q=city+address_with_number` I get info window with address, zip code, city and country name.

Answer (score 0):

This was possible with the old maps by appending the desired caption, surrounded by parentheses, to the q-parameter:

https://maps.google.com/?output=classic&q=Berlin(I%20live%20here)&iwloc=A

But all of these URL-parameters have never been officially documented. When you use it with the new maps( https://www.google.com/maps/preview/?q=Berlin%28I%20live%20here%29&iwloc=A )  the caption will not be present in the redirect-URL, so I would assume that it's not possible with the new maps.